Azure Functions project - Can't load file from present NuGet package
I have consolidated some old WebJobs and worker roles into a new Azure Function project. I have used Azure Functions before with no trouble. This project has a persistent problem I have been battling for a few days. It throws the following error in the console window:

System.Private.CoreLib: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Storage.Queues: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Memory.Data, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'. The system cannot find the file specified.
Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'provider')

This error showed up with an old version of the project. I rebuilt it from scratch using .NET 6.0. It worked for a while but then the error returned. The current environment is:
Visual Studio 17.11.5,
Azure Functions and Web Jobs tools 17.11.231.19466
I have tried numerous combinations of NuGet package versions. Relevant (I think) NuGet packages are:
Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Storage 5.3.3,
Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions 4.5.0"
I have also tried removing Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Storage and replacing it with Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Storage.Queues with no result.
I have searched extensively and found no reference matching my error. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciates.
Thanks in advance,
Robert Keith

Please share the function code and .csproj file @Rob

I just had a similar Issue. Update only the SDK functions to '4.5.0' and not the Azure.WebJobs.Extension.Storage

It is basically not possible to upgrade Azure Functions from an earlier version of .NET  to .NET 8.0. Just build a new project with all the functions and then add the code for each function from the old project.

Make sure that you are using version 4.x of the AzureFunctions runtime: <AzureFunctionsVersion>v4</AzureFunctionsVersion> should be present in your .csproj file.
Older runtime versions are not compatible with .NET 6 and runtime libraries in version 6.x.x are therefore missing, which could explain your error.
See the official Migrate apps from Azure Functions version 3.x to version 4.x documentation.

Thank you for the reply. The csproj file has the v4 line present.
I previously had no problem with the old project, which I had migrated from .NET 4.8 to  6.0, and then to 8.0. However, when I added some new functions to it, it threw the same error.
I created the current project from scratch. I had three functions in it; one queue triggered and two timer triggered functions. That worked fine. Then I added more functions (there are 14) and the same old error came back again.
The file in question, system.memory.data v. 6.0.0, is not missing. It is sitting where it should be

Apparently more modern versions are incompatible too! I had to revert my packages back to Balakumaran’s versions for Azure to stop throwing errors. Microsoft’s QC is awful!

Thanks again. I solved my problem by generating my project again completely from scratch as a .NET 8.0 project. It does no seem possible to upgrade an old Functions project.
One example is that old versions of the project included references to WebJobs. These WebJobs libraries are not supported under .NET 8.0 so a whole different set of NuGet packages were required. FWIW these are more elegant and streamlined. It all works very well now.

Please try "Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Storage" "5.3.2" Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions" Version="4.4.0"

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

Thanks for the reply. I tried that combination and got exactly the same error.

The same issue plagued my .Net6 AzFn project. I did not want to upgrade to .Net8, but if i did I would use the UpgradeAssistant.
To remain using the .net6 Azfn, as per the comment from @mrah:
Change:
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions" Version="4.4.0" />

To:
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions" Version="4.5.0" />

DO NOT upgrade to 4.6.0
